# Is it okay to mention awards twice in a CV, once in the experience and once in the awards section?

Tags: resume

I was told my a reviewer that I should not "double dip" awards in my CV. For example:

**University of XYZ, College of XYZ**

- XYZ Fullride Scholarship

**Experiences**.

- Experience #1: Description..."received first place in XYZ national meeting"

[Towards the end of my resume]

**Awards and achievements**:

- XYZ Fullride Scholarship: [Insert description]
- XYZ National meeting award 2020: [Insert description]
- Other awards...

I personally thought it was okay to mention awards twice in this manner because one is being used in the context of an experience (and in some cases, explains the experience well) while the other is a comprehensive list of all the awards I have won. Would you agree or should I remove mention of these awards in my experiences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put whatever you like on your CV, but if you're trying to condense your whole academic and professional life into one or two pages, eventually you run out of space. Mentioning the same thing twice looks like you're trying to                                            fill space, from which a reader might infer you feel you haven't much to say for yourself.

If you have an 'experience' section and an 'awards' section you're better off describing what you did and the experience you gained in the former, and list the award in the latter.

At the beginning of your career, you might include more detail of experiences, and lower levels of award that you condense and/or drop as you progress through your career - when you first leave school, being top of your class in history, elected to the school council or captain of a sports team may be a big deal but by the time you're 40, you should have plenty to write about that is more recent and relevant to your career and these things are left out.

Answer (score 3):

Double-dipping is a clear sign that you **don't have more to show**.

This isn't an absolute rule. There are some cases where you'd want to double-dip. For instance, "Directed Inception (Academy Award winner)" in Work History and "3 Oscar, 5 Academy awards" in Achievements is totally appropriate. You're clarifying why directing Inception was a meaningful step in your career.

Scholarship awards are on the extreme low end of achievements. They're barely worth mentioning at all, except in paperwork meant for internal use within your college, much less twice.

Your resume is, in part, a demonstration of your ability to condense and present information. Remove anything redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Your reviewer is correct - Mention it once, in the most applicable section.

If the experience of getting the Award is more applicable to the position you are after, then list it there

If the awarding of the prize is more applicable, then list it there.

But listing it twice is at best gauche, at worst annoying.

And if I'm annoyed reading your CV, guess where it goes?